# Batch Arcpy TIFF export from data view

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to export 150 individual TIFF files from a large dataset. I got a script that it seems to work but it generates TIFFs at default resolution but not at the desired one.

First, some words about my problem. 
Let’s say I have a big dataset of building blocks of a city and I want to perform a batch georeferenced TIFF export based on a grid that I have constructed. 
My grid is called **Grid_file.shp** and I wrote a script that zooms to every part of the grid and then performs the export process. It seems to work but the generated TIFFs are at the default resolution (96dpi) and not at the desired one (300dpi) any ideas?
Here’s my code:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Grid_file", df)[0]
for x in range (0,12):
 arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", ' "Id" = %d '%(x))
 df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF (mxd, r'C:\temp\%d.tif' %(x), df, 5030, 2855, 300, True, "8-BIT_PALETTE", "NONE",True)
```

I'm using ArcInfo 10.2.2, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the Help file, under the discussion section of the [ExportToTIFF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttotiff.htm) function it says to keep dpi at 96 and alter height and width if you are exporting the dataframe. I believe the dpi is only relevant for page layout exports?

Have you considered [data driven pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/map-export-and-print/exporting-data-driven-pages.htm)?

Comment: I tried data driven pages (ddp) first but no luck.. I got the same issue. I'll give it a try with resolution set to default and I'll get back at you. Thanks

Comment: Sadly no result..